# UITextField and UITableViewCell autoscrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

**Is the following the best way to handle scrolling with UITextFields and tall UITableViewCells?**

I have a UITableView with tall cells and UITextFields inside of it, distributed from top to bottom. By tall, I mean that when the keyboard pops up, the entire cell can't be displayed.

When relying on the default behaviour, autoscrolling doesn't work when a UITextField located at the top of the cell is selected. It seems to be pretty basic and to always scroll to the bottom position, which results in the topmost UITextFields (including the one selected) being hidden.

As a result, I use UIKeyboardWillShow/UIKeyboardDidShow notifications.

I tried at first to use this behaviour for the UITextFields at the top only, relying on default behaviour otherwise, but for some reason the autoscrolling would not be reliable anymore, so I went with manual scrolling for everything.

Here's the (somewhat "classic") code I'm using.
**Basically, I just tell the tableview where to scroll to, changing the UITableViewScrollPosition according to the UITextField being selected**

```
var scrollTo: (indexPath: IndexPath, position: UITableViewScrollPosition)?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    unregisterForKeyboardNotifications()
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}

func unregisterForKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow() {
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = scrollTo == nil
}

func keyboardDidShow() {
    guard let scrollTo = scrollTo else { return }
    self.scrollTo = nil
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: scrollTo.indexPath, at: scrollTo.position, animated: true)
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
}

/// Textfields are tagged to allow UITextFieldDelegate method identification
/// I renamed each text field according to its location in the cell for sake of clarity
enum CellTextField: Int {
    case topFieldA = 1, topFieldB, middleFieldA, bottomFieldA, bottomFieldB

    static let multiplier = 10

    static func identifiersFrom(cellTag: Int) -> (cellTextField: CellTextField, indexPath: IndexPath)? {
        guard let cellTextField = CellTextField(rawValue: cellTag % CellTextField.multiplier) else {
            return nil
        }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: cellTag / CellTextField.multiplier, section: 0)
        return (cellTextField, indexPath)
    }

    func tagFor(row: Int) -> Int {
        return row * CellTextField.multiplier + self.rawValue
    }
}

/// When the textfield is selected, I retrieve the indexPath from the textfield tag
/// (set by tableView(tableView:cellForRowAt indexPath:)) and set the most relevant
//// scrollTo position according to the textfield position in the cell
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    guard let identifiers = CellTextField.identifiersFrom(cellTag: textField.tag) else { return true }
    switch identifiers.cellTextField {
    case .topFieldA, . topFieldB:
        scrollTo = (identifiers.indexPath, .top)
    case . middleFieldA:
        scrollTo = (identifiers.indexPath, .middle)
    case .bottomFieldA, . bottomFieldB:
        scrollTo = (identifiers.indexPath, .bottom)
    }
    return true
}
```

**The above code works fine, it just seems like a lot of overhead for the crime of having tall cells. Or is it the correct way to handle this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take the lack of answers as one: yes, this is the correct way to handle it.